# Doubts regarding to table, producer/consumer locking solutions

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, locking

Context: Let's say we have a service with 500 clients connected that are on constant activity, and I want to log most part of it by inserting them on a MySQL InnoDB based table. The server is working on a simple thread.

From an external program (website), I proceed selecting data from that table, will it cause it to be locked?
In case it does, I assume the server won't be able to proceed on inserting or updating data until the selecting task is finished from the external program.

The first thing that came to my mind was to implement a producer-consumer concurrency, where one will push data into a queue, and another would insert that data into the database; so, in case of selecting data from an external program, the consumer won't proceed and not the whole server.

I've seen some consumer/producer examples where the producer is not able to push data while it is being processed. In this case, is it ok to make two containers, and simply push it on the one that is not being used? Since, if the consumer is procesing the data, the producer won't proceed pushing it into the queue, making me doubt about its efficiency.
Also, I have been looking into this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43510/Lock-Free-Single-Producer-Single-Consumer-Circular
In case it works as it describes, is there anything I should be worried about? Is there something I'm missing?
In case the select query takes too much and the inserting query returns a time out, would it be recomendable to increase the timeout value or to retry the query in case of failure?

Thanks

Comment: Mysql is already implementing access concurrency in its engine, as any ACID compliant database server should. Table locking depends on how you've setup the server and the session.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: Of course, when hitting the db from a single app, in order to make use of db concurrency, your app middle tier will have to be multithreaded, and sort its queries so as to minimise contention.

Comment: IMHO, you should first *try* to implement a simple model for your app, and benchmark. At this point you seem to ponder on issues which may not have a significant impact depending on the volume of data your app will be processing.

Comment: @didierc Thanks, I'll look into benchmark and transaction model.

Comment: I am sorry if my comments have been rude. Stackoverflow is very much centered on real code, as opposed to hypothetical scenarios. If you want to discuss the later, may I kindly suggest posting to programmers.stackexchange.com instead? It may also be possible to migrate this very question as well, but you will need the help of a moderator.